# Typing constructor functions in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm having problems understanding how to correctly type a constructor function in TS. I'm aware that a common answer would be to use a class, but I'm currently exploring TS features. In my `tsconfig.json` I have `noImplicitAny: true`.

My constructor function looks like this in JS:

```
function User(username) {
     this.username = username
}
User.prototype.age = 57
```

My first attempt to type the functions relied on the [TS docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#call-signatures) that explain how to define call signatures:

```
interface IUser {
    username: string;
    age: number;
}

type UserConstructor = {
    (username: string): void;
    new (username: string): IUser;
}

const User: UserConstructor = function(username: string) {
    this.username = username
}
User.prototype.age = 57
```

The compiler complains since the value of `this` is unknown and the call signatures don't seem to match.

After doing some research, I was able to come up with a version that works but I don't really like it:

```
interface ICUser {
    username: string;
    age: number;
}

function ConstructedUser(this:ICUser, username: string) {
    this.username = username;
}

ConstructedUser.prototype.dateOfBirth = "Freb"
```

Here's what I don't like about solution nr. 2:

- I'm not sure I completely understand the explicit passing of this since there aren't any official docs on this.
- The typing is very verbose and does not separate between properties on the instance and prototype chain.

I wasn't able to find good resources on how to type constructor functions and hoped someone might be able to help.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you don't want to use the `class` syntax? Typescript can compile it to a constructor function if you set the target language level appropriately.

Comment: I'm actually not trying to solve any "real world" problem. I'm just exploring how this would work in TS to learn.

Comment: This answer is kind of late, but the this usage is officially documented since [Typescript 2](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#specifying-the-type-of-this-for-functions)

Comment: Also check [this part](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#declaring-this-in-a-function) and [this other part](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/migrating-from-javascript.html#no-implicit-any-for-this)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the answer is that you can't do this without type assertions (e.g. `as any`), because you aren't supposed to write constructor functions in Typescript. [This GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2310) suggests allowing it, and the suggestion was marked as "declined" and closed:

> If anything we'd rather remove the ability to new void functions. The inconsistency is unfortunate but we didn't want to add a large type safety hole for the sake of consistency with a facet we don't even like in the first place.

The proper way to write your code in Typescript is using the `class` syntax to declare a class. If it's needed for compatibility with older browsers, you can force `tsc` to convert your class declaration into a constructor function during compilation, by setting the target language level to ES3 or ES5.